# axios call to jsp file

Tags: reactjs, jsp, axios

I am making a axios call from a react file to a jsp file called getAuditData.jsp

```
axios.post('ajax/parserAudit/getAuditData.jsp', {'name':'john','class':'8'}
        ).then(response => {
            //Success response processing
          
        }).catch(error => {
// Error handling
        }).then(() => {
          
        });
```

And I want to access this data (i.e. {'name':'john','class':'8'}) in the jsp file getAuditData.jsp.
I tried using request.getParameter() but it does not work.

Comment: Explain more briefly

Comment: Pay attention that you are specifying a **relative** path. try to add `/` at the beginning of the path